# Steering wheel vibration

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, steering, vibration, camaro

While driving my 2012 camaro at freeway speeds, the steering wheel vibrates violently.  However, it will continue to vibrate intermittently even after braking every few seconds.

Comment: You really don't give any real information here. Does this happen at all or certain speeds? How many miles on your car? Which engine/transmission does it have? What size tires does the car have? Have you had any work done to the vehicle lately? Is it just the steering wheel, or does it feel like it is localized to one portion of your car? Where do you live? Is it still cold and have you had a lot of snow lately?

Answer (score 1):

Take it to a tire place and let them ask you questions.  There's not enough info here to answer.  It could be tires out of balance, steering dampener issues, loose linkages, etc.  This one cannot be diagnosed online probably, but the most likely thing on a car that new is that your wheels are out of balance - a cheap and easy thing for a tire place to remedy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no mechanic, but in my personal experience vibrations of the wheel are typically caused by uneven/scarred rotors.

Answer (score 0):

If it only occurs after braking, it could be a warped rotor or sticky caliper. If the brake pedal feels like it vibrates when braking then it's most likely warped rotors. 
If your fuel economy is lower than usual then it's possibly a sticky brake caliper. 
Another possibility is a bad wheel bearing.  Put the car on jack stands and try making the wheels wobble. If they do, it's likely a wheel bearing. 
The last option that comes to mind is an imbalanced wheel. 
Before you cough up money on a suspension job, take it to a tire shop and have them balance your wheels. If it persists, check for a bad bearing.